# version changes once imported in another module

Tags: java, maven

I have an `api` module and a `service` module. The `api` uses the `service`
 and the `service` uses mysql connector version **6**.

```
api
|-service
     |-mysql 6
```

The problem is when I look at the dependency tree, mysql becomes version **5** in the api module.

```
+- com.foo:service:jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.threeten:threetenbp:jar:1.3.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.17.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.22.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.46:compile
```

I don't understand how this is possible.

How come the version changes from 6 to 5? There is no other mysql dependency anywhere else.

Complete Maven dependency tree

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Service 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ service ---
[INFO] com.foo:service:jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.17.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.17.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.17.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.17.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.17.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.threeten:threetenbp:jar:1.3.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.17.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.17.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.5.0-b42:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-entity-filtering:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.22.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:6.0.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:jar:4.2.1:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.querydsl:querydsl-codegen:jar:4.2.1:provided
[INFO] |     +- com.mysema.codegen:codegen:jar:0.6.8:provided
[INFO] |     |  \- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:jar:4.3.1:provided
[INFO] |     \- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.9:provided
[INFO] |        \- com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:jar:2.0.1:provided
[INFO] \- com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO]    +- com.querydsl:querydsl-core:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.mysema.commons:mysema-commons-lang:jar:0.2.4:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.infradna.tool:bridge-method-annotation:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO]    \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building api 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:tree (default-cli) @ api ---
[INFO] com.foo:api:jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.31:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.10.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-spring4:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.5.0-b42:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.5.0-b42:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2:jar:2.5.0-b42:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.5.0-b42:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.5.0-b42:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:config-types:jar:2.5.0-b42:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-core:jar:2.5.0-b42:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-config:jar:2.5.0-b42:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-runlevel:jar:2.5.0-b42:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:class-model:jar:2.5.0-b42:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:asm-all-repackaged:jar:2.5.0-b42:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:spring-bridge:jar:2.5.0-b42:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-entity-filtering:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-server:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-servlet:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-server-impl:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-client-impl:jar:9.4.11.v20180605:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mortbay.jasper:apache-el:jar:8.5.24.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.foo:service:jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.threeten:threetenbp:jar:1.3.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.17.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.22.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.46:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:jar:4.1.4:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.querydsl:querydsl-core:jar:4.1.4:compile
[INFO] |        +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |        +- com.mysema.commons:mysema-commons-lang:jar:0.2.4:compile
[INFO] |        \- com.infradna.tool:bridge-method-annotation:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.7.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:20.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] \- io.swagger:swagger-jersey2-jaxrs:jar:1.5.13:compile
[INFO]    +- io.swagger:swagger-jaxrs:jar:1.5.13:compile
[INFO]    |  +- io.swagger:swagger-core:jar:1.5.13:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.7:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.10:compile
[INFO]    |     \- com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO]    \- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO]       \- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.9.6:compile
```

Api pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
            <artifactId>service</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.13</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>jar-with-all-dependencies</classifier>
                            <mainClass>
                              ${main-class-path}
                            </mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

service pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.foo</groupId>
<artifactId>service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org-springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org-springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${org-springframework-data.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
        <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
       <version>${org-springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-media-json-jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${apt-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/apt</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I could see you landing in this state is if you changed the version for the `mysql-connector` in the service but did not run `mvn install` after the change. This will cause maven to check the dependency tree on the service based on the latest version of the service pom when run on the service but use an older version of the service pom that is installed in your .m2 when run from the api which has a dependency to the service.

Comment: I purged all the dependencies and upgraded the version from 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT to 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT